# Is there a way to store the help of a function in a variable?

Tags: powershell

We have several functions within a PowerShell module. Some of these functions share the same parameter and as such the same help text should be displayed when using `Get-Help`.

**Example**

```
// myModule.psm1
Function Add-Foo {
    <#
    .PARAMETER AddTen
        Adds ten to the result
    #>
}

Function Add-Bar {
    <#
    .PARAMETER AddTen
        Adds ten to the result
    #>
}
```

It would be great to do something like this:

```
// myModule.psm1
$AddTen = "Adds ten to the result"

Function Add-Foo {
    <#
    .PARAMETER AddTen
        $AddTen
    #>
}

Function Add-Bar {
    <#
    .PARAMETER AddTen
        $AddTen
    #>
}
```

Comment: Probably need to look at using a powershell data file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile?view=powershell-7  http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PowerShell-Configuration-Data/